# Unable to Scrape Public Data on Drinking Water Standards for Chemicals - "failed to load HTTP reosurce" error

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to scrape a table with USEPA drinking water standards for a list of 122 chemicals. The table and data are publically available here: http://www.epa.gov/wqc/national-recommended-water-quality-criteria-human-health-criteria-table

I am trying to use the XML package.

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.epa.gov/wqc/national-recommended-water-quality-criteria-human-health-criteria-table"
classes <- c('character', 'integer', 'FormattedNumber', 'FormattedNumber', 'Integer', 'Character')
USEPA <- readHTMLTable(url,which=1,colClasses=classes,stringAsFactors=F)
```

Unfortunately I only get this error message in return:
"Error: failed to load HTTP resource"

Answer (score 1):

If I follow the link you give above, my browser automatically takes me to the `https` site.

My guess is that there may not be a `http` version....only the `https` version. That might present a problem for the XML library.

Here's a way you can read the data, based on a blog post here: [Using rvest to Scrape an HTML Table](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/)

```
library("rvest")
url <- "https://www.epa.gov/wqc/national-recommended-water-quality-criteria-human-health-criteria-table"
table_list <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  # I copied this Xpath as described in the blog post I linked above
  html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table') %>%
  html_table() 

# we have a list, but need to get the first item (the table)
html_table = table_list[[1]]
head(html_table[, 1:2]) # show only first two columns
```

Output:

```
                              Pollutant CAS Number
1                      Acenaphthene (P)      83329
2                          Acrolein (P)     107028
3                     Acrylonitrile (P)     107131
4                            Aldrin (P)     309002
5 alpha-Hexachlorocyclohexane (HCH) (P)     319846
6                  alpha-Endosulfan (P)     959988
```

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org) solution using the rvest package. The key concept is you can use the **xpath** of the HTML table as mentioned [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/). You may want to further rename the columns using the tidyr [rename](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/rename]) function.
Also as mentioned by the warning messages, you might want to leave some columns as characters and manually correct any problematic values and then do the type conversion.

```r
# install.package('rvest')
# install.package('tidyverse')

library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(tidyverse)

url <- "http://www.epa.gov/wqc/national-recommended-water-quality-criteria-human-health-criteria-table"

df <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table') %>% # https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/
  html_table() %>%
  purrr::pluck(1) %>% # pluck out first item in the list which is a df
  readr::type_convert(col_types = "cinnic") # c is character type, and i is integer, ...
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [70, 2]: expected an integer, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [77, 2]: expected an integer, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [80, 2]: expected an integer, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [85, 2]: expected an integer, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [17, 3]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [26, 3]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [34, 3]: expected a number, but got 'Total'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [35, 3]: expected a number, but got 'Total'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [63, 3]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [77, 3]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [9, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [10, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [17, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [26, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [34, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [35, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [37, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [68, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [77, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [80, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [85, 4]: expected a number, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [17, 5]: expected an integer, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [26, 5]: expected an integer, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [34, 5]: expected an integer, but got '—'
#> Warning in type_convert_col(char_cols[[i]], specs$cols[[i]],
#> which(is_character)[i], : [35, 5]: expected an integer, but got '—'

glimpse(df)
#> Observations: 122
#> Variables: 6
#> $ Pollutant                                                              <chr> …
#> $ `CAS Number`                                                           <int> …
#> $ `Human Health for the consumption of Water + Organism\n\t\t\t\t(µg/L)` <dbl> …
#> $ `Human Health for the consumption of Organism Only\n\t\t\t\t(µg/L)`    <dbl> …
#> $ `Publication Year`                                                     <int> …
#> $ Notes                                                                  <chr> …
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.

Comment: Note that the xpath given in the example has an error but once corrected it works fine: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/